# Why do WordPress adds the id="handle-{js|css}" attribute to scripts and stylesheet?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

When you enqueue a script the `id=""` attribute and the script handle (appended with the `-js` or `-css` termination) are automatically added to the generated `<script>` or `<style>` tag.

What is the purpose behind it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute was added to the `<style>` tags in WordPress [v4.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/query?group=status&component=Script+Loader&milestone=4.1) (2014) — see the Trac changesets [29956](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/29956) and [29958](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/29958/) which both mentioned [ticket #30032](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30032) ("*Add ID attribute to style element from `wp_add_inline_style()`*"):

> In order to support partial preview refreshes
> ([#27355](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27355)), it is important for all
> partials being updated to have an element with a distinct CSS selector
> for targeting. In the case of Twenty Fifteen, styles output via
> `wp_add_inline_style()` may be dynamically refreshed by JS and so the
> `style` elements output by this function should have distinct IDs.
> Once this is…

As for the `<script>` tags, the `id` attribute was added in WordPress v5.5 (2020) — see the Trac changeset [48295](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/48295/) (see description below) and [ticket #48654](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48654), and [`wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5/src/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php) for WordPress v5.5.

> Script Loader: Add id attributes to script assets.
>
> This commit adds a unique ID attribute to script loader generated
> `<script>` tags as well as related `<script>` tags for inline
> JavaScript, translations, or parameters.
>
> This is a first step in adding support for lazy loading scripts and
> styles, but for now is only used to assist in debugging generated
> output.